# How to check innodb history list length?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.6

The output for `show engine innodb status` has the history list length as a number, but that output is hard to parse, and there's just too much data when all you want is a single value. Is the value available somewhere else that can be fetched as a row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find documentation confirming it anywhere, but I think it's:

`select count from information_schema.innodb_metrics where name = 'trx_rseg_history_len';`

The closest thing to a confirmation is a [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76750) referring to this counter as the history list length. Also, the current, min and max values match the logs I have recorded. It would be nice if someone familiar with the MySQL source code could confirm it.

Comment: That works (and the value agrees) on my 5.6.12.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what version you have.  Here is the `STATUS` value:

`Innodb_history_list_length`

```
Description: History list length as shown in the TRANSACTIONS
    section of the SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS output.
Scope: Global
Data Type: numeric
Introduced: MariaDB 5.5 / XtraDB 5.5.8-20
```

(quoted from:) https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/xtradbinnodb-server-status-variables/#innodb_history_list_length

So I would expect the 'fetch' to look like

```
SELECT VARIABLE_VALUE
     FROM information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS
     WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'Innodb_history_list_length';
```

Comment: It's MySQL 5.6.22 on AWS RDS. Unfortunately, that doesn't work, but I think I figured it out. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that the `SELECT ... FROM GLOBAL_STATUS ...` worked briefly in some later versions of 5.5 and 5.6, not not in other versions.  It's elusive!